# Check in a View if is an upate or a create operation?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have some operations that I do in `form_valid` (method on GCBV) that are repeated in multiple views.

Also the operations for views that inherits from CreateView or UpdateView are very similar.

So I want to create a class where I write a generic 'form_valid', and all other View inherit from that class, something like:

```
AssocUpdateView(BaseClass, UpdateView)
AssocCreateView(BaseClass, CreateView)
```

So for create and update there is a small variation, so I need to know when I'm creating and when I'm updating in `form_valid`. It is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether `form.instance.pk is None`.

Comment: Yes it does. How does it not? It's a full and complete answer to working out whether the operation is an update our create in the firm_valid method.

Comment: You are correct, I have retracted the comment. Thanks.